# Taking a picture with the AVD

Tags: camera, camera-calibration

I'm testing my app on the AVD emulator ; one of the steps of my App is to take a picture ; when I get there, I get the right screen first (the one that has a take a picture and a Cancel buttons) but after a few seconds, before I can take the picture, I get this error message "The application Camera (process com.android.camera) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Is this the expected behavior, because I'm using an AVD?

FWIW, I added all hardware options to my AVD, and my code is modified from this link http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture

Any help is appreciated.

rh4games